# How can I achieve this selection in SAS

Tags: select, sas

say I have a SAS table `tbl` which has a column `col`. This column `col` holds different values say `{"a","s","d","f",...}` but one is MUCH more present than the other (say `"d"`). How can I do a select only this value

It would be something like

```
data tbl;
  set tbl;
  where col eq "the most present element of col in this case d";
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use PROC SQL for this.

Here's an example that gets "d" into a macro variable and then filters the original dataset, as requested in your question.

This will work even if there is a multi-way tie for the most frequent observation.

```
data tbl;
    input col: $1.;
    datalines;
    a
    a
    b
    b
    b
    b
    c
    c
    c
    c
    d
    d
    d
;run;

proc sql noprint;
    create table tbl_freq as
    select col, count(*) as freq
    from tbl
    group by col;    

    select quote(col) into: mode_values separated by ', '
    from tbl_freq
    where freq = (select max(freq) from tbl_freq);
quit;

%put mode_values = &mode_values.;

data tbl_filtered;
    set tbl;
    where col in (&mode_values.);
run;
```

Note the use of QUOTE(), which is needed to wrap the values of col in quotation marks (omit this if col is a numeric variable).

Answer (score 3):

One of many methods to accomplish this...

```
data test;
n+1;
input col $;
datalines;
a
b
c
d
d
d
d
e
f
g
d
d
a
b
d
d
;
run;

proc freq data=test order=freq;  *order=freq automatically puts the most frequent on top;
tables col/out=test_count;
run;

data want;
set test;
if _n_ = 1 then set test_count(keep=col rename=col=col_keep);
if col = col_keep;
run;
```

To put this into a macro variable (see comments):

```
data _null_;
set test_count;
call symput("mvar",col); *put it to a macro variable;
stop;                    *only want the first row;
run;
```

Comment: You can save yourself the sort by adding ORDER=FREQ to the proc freq statement.

Comment: Ah, that's what the option was.  In too much of a hurry to look it up, thanks!

Comment: Thnaks but I'd rather get "d" in a macro-variable how can I do this ?

Comment: For one, your question should probably refer to the macro variable requirement.  If you want it in a macro variable, it's much easier.

Comment: How do you handle ties using this method?

Comment: Ties would be up to the user to handle.  The specific request was for the one most frequent value (and specified "much more", implying there aren't ties, but anyway).  If multiple are desired, and you're using a macro variable, then you could do `set test_count; by count;` and then construct a (retained) variable by catting each col together, then symput `if last.count;` then stopping.

Comment: I think my solution is more elegant :)